# Why did so many souls continue to exist in Jallianwala Bagh?

Tags: phillauri

In Phillauri (2017) movie, it was explicitly told that a soul remains Earth-bound so long as its desire at the time of death remains unfulfilled. I think the main soul herself told it. She even got freedom from Earth after meeting her boyfriend’s soul in the end (she had committed suicide because her boyfriend who had impregnated her didn’t come for their marriage).

In the end, we learned that her boyfriend couldn’t come because he got killed in [Jallianwala Bagh massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jallianwala_Bagh_massacre) in which British Empire had massacred thousands of pro-independence peaceful protesters. In the same place, large number of souls appeared. But, why were those souls still there? All those people wanted independence of India at the time of death (1919) and India already got independence back in 1947 (present day events of the movie happen in 2017). Then, why were those souls still there?